# When to use coroutines over iterators?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

Let's say I have data that I want to provide 'one at a time'. There's lots of data, which is why I get one piece only when it's needed (to save on memory). So I can't store the whole data inside a `std::vector`.

Today I can use iterators for this, as they naturally fit this requirement. But I could also use coroutines (currently using the Coroutines TS). Using algorithms that only use iterators is not needed.

Is there any advantage of using coroutines over iterators in this case?

Comment: I assume you are referring to stream iterators? Otherwise, the range has to be already stored somewhere.

Comment: @Fureeish effectively yes :)

Comment: I suppose a coroutine is an iterator which would store, between each iteration a quantity of information that may vary (the stack of the coroutine) and for which each iteration would involve a computation that depends on this stored information. So I think that if you do not have to store a varying quantity of information between each iteration to compute the iteration or if the algorithm used to compute the next iteration does not varies, co-routine may not be a better choice than an iterator holding some state.

Comment: @Rakete1111: "*Using algorithms that only use iterators is not needed.*" Then why were you using iterators to begin with?

Comment: Coroutines are a form of cooperative multitasking. Blocking IO (as part of the stream iterator) will block the thread, so the cooperation is gone. There is thus no point in mixing blocking IO with coroutines.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's still useful to have a `it` iterator that I can dereference and increment to get data even if I'm not using any `<algorithm>`. I could have also used a `getCurrent()` and `consume()` function.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Why is that specific interface "useful" compared to explicit function calls? The only reason I can come up with for using it is that it's the standard idiom, therefore there's code out there that expects and uses it. That code being "algorithms" and the like. But if you don't need compatibility with code using the iterator paradigm, then it is not objectively better than any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators act as a kind of glue, allowing users to write algorithms that operate over sequences of values without knowing about how that sequence got there or is held. But the specific "glue" between the algorithm and the sequence is irrelevant. It only matters in that a specific implementation of an algorithm has to be implemented in terms of a specific kind of "glue".

The standard library iterator model is useful because the standard library comes with tools that use this model (algorithms, the iterator constructors of containers, range-based `for`, etc). If you're not actually using those mechanisms... then there is nothing objective to be gained by using the iterator model compared to any other model. You could just have an object that has a `get_next` function and a `has_next`, or some similar interface. They're all approximately equally efficient, and it's not hard to convert from one to the other.

Coroutines would only be useful in this regard to the degree that it simplifies the *implementation* of the operation. The code using the generation coroutine would have basically the same interface as it had before; it just internally is using `co_yield` and a stack frame that pauses and resumes.

Because the stack frame of a coroutine is an object that persists, you don't need to explicitly create a generation object. The function which generates values can use stack variables for its state, then `co_yield` values from that stack data as need. That would allow you to build a generalized generator framework that many distinct functions could use, thus creating some separation between the general interface for all generators and the specific code doing the generation.